# Open Acumatica screen as popup without righthand navigation pane

Tags: acumatica

I have code to open an Acumatica screen using the following:

```
var url = "http://localhost/AcumaticaDB2562/?ScreenId=AC302000&OpenSourceName=Bills+and+Adjustments&DataID=" + apinvoice.RefNbr;
throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(url, "Open Source")
{
     Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow
};
```

Where I'm passing in parameters via the Querystring.  This works fine, but I want it to open without the left hand Navigation Pane, similar to what happens when you open a Case from the list of cases in 'Business Accounts' Cases tab.

In addition - is there a way to specify or retrieve the url of the current instance of Acumatica that I'm in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter, PXRedirectToUrlException is not intended to open an Acumatica screen. As Brendan suggested earlier ([How to open a screen as popup from Site Map location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448961/how-to-open-a-screen-as-popup-from-site-map-location)), you should be using PXRedirectRequiredException with Mode property set to NewWindow.

The code snippet below shows how to create a button on the Invoices screen to open Batch generated for the invoice in a new window without the left hand Navigation Pane:

```
public class SOInvoiceEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOInvoiceEntry>
{
    public void ARInvoice_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        ARInvoice doc = (ARInvoice)e.Row;
        if (doc == null) return;

        OpenBatch.SetEnabled(doc.BatchNbr != null);
    }

    public PXAction<ARInvoice> OpenBatch;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Open Batch")]
    protected void openBatch()
    {
        ARInvoice doc = Base.Document.Current;
        if (doc != null && doc.BatchNbr != null)
        {
            JournalEntry entry = PXGraph.CreateInstance<JournalEntry>();
            entry.BatchModule.Current = entry.BatchModule.Search<Batch.batchNbr>(doc.BatchNbr, "AR");
            if (entry.BatchModule.Current != null)
            {
                throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(entry, "Open Invoice Batch")
                {
                    Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Once switched to PXRedirectRequiredException, you won't have to retrieve the url of the current instance of Acumatica.

Let's say, you developed a custom screen, which opens just fine from the Navigation Pane:

```
namespace ActionMenuAddOn
{
    public class TaskTemplateMaint : PXGraph<TaskTemplateMaint, TaskTemplate>
    {
        public PXSelect<TaskTemplate> Templates;
    }
}
```

[image]

However, with PXRedirectRequiredException thrown to open the custom screen in new window, we get an error "*You have insufficient rights to access object (TaskTemplateMaint)*":

```
using ActionMenuAddOn;
...

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOInvoiceEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOInvoiceEntry>
    {
        public void ARInvoice_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            ARInvoice doc = (ARInvoice)e.Row;
            if (doc == null) return;

            OpenTaskTemplate.SetEnabled(doc.BatchNbr != null);
        }

        ...

        public PXAction<ARInvoice> OpenTaskTemplate;
        [PXButton]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Open Task Template")]
        protected void openTaskTemplate()
        {
            TaskTemplateMaint templateMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance<TaskTemplateMaint>();
            templateMaint.Templates.Current = templateMaint.Templates.Search<TaskTemplate.templateCD>("000001");
            if (templateMaint.Templates.Current != null)
            {
                throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(templateMaint, "Open Task Template")
                {
                    Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To get over the error, open the **Access Rights By Role** screen and grant access for  custom screen at least to Administrator role as shown on the screenshot below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: My problem is that the screen I'm opening is a completely custom screen with its own BLC / graph.  I don't have access to that unless I provide all the graph logic in the class library project.  I've done that, but I get an error when running it:

"You have insufficient rights to access object (myGraph)"

That's why I went back to the other method which just opens a URL.

Comment: This means that no access rights were granted to your custom page. Can you open the Access Rights By Screen or the Access Rights By Role screen and grant access at least to Administrator role? - this must resolve the issue. In case you don't need to have custom page in the Navigation Pane, it must be added into Hidden folder (accessible from SiteMap root)

Comment: I have complete access to the custom screens in the usual manner, i.e., through the navigation pane.  They open without any problem.  I don't understand why opening the screen this way would be any different from opening through the graph code you suggested.  I'm not sure how I would modify the Access Rights by Role or Access Rights by Screen to change this.

Comment: Before you responded, I had done exactly that with no effect.  Still won't access it.

Comment: I guess you should file a support request for us to review your package and identify the root cause.